# Does new spouse have to go on the house title when it's refinanced?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance, fha

The home was purchased when the mortgagee was single; they've subsequently married. They're attempting an FHA streamline refi, and the mortgage broker told them it was *required* for the new spouse to go on the title for the refinance.

Is this true? Or is the mortgage broker blowing smoke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It varies by state. [Here is a list](https://www.worldwidelandtransfer.com/marital-signature-requirements/).

Note that once a couple is married, the spouse could become part owner of the house regardless of whether or not they are on the title. This means when it comes time to sell the house, the spouse's signature could be required even if not on the title. This is probably why the refi is requiring the spouse to be put on the title even if they are not on the mortgage. It's to make the title reflect reality since the moment they were married the title became incorrect.